# Collapse bootstrap card on sm and\or md screens

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I use bootstrap 4.1 card to display inside categories on right sidebar - [Card example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K96ke.png);

On small screens I want to collapse this `card`, because it is big and goes first - [mobile example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XJWBq.png).

So how can I collapse card on `sm` and `md` screens, and not collapse on `lg` screens? Or I need not to use `card`?

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container">
  <div class="card mb-3">
    <h5 class="card-header">Categories</h5>
    <div class="card-body">
      <h5><a href="http://rtss2.loc/info">All</a></h5>
      Categories here
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
<button class="btn d-lg-none" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#example-collapse">
    <span class="navbar-light"><span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span></span>
</button>

<div id="example-collapse" class="collapse d-lg-block">
    <!-- your card here -->
</div>
```

The class `d-lg-none` hides the button for `lg` and `xl` screen sizes and the class `d-lg-block` shows the div for `lg` and `xl` screen sizes. I am using the collapse icon for the `navbar-light` style, you may need to adjust this to match your navbar.

Comment: Big thanks! I can't add +1 because I have only 9 reputation. But I mark your answer as solution.

Comment: Hi, i wanted to the same, but for small screens (sm/xs) but when I do d-sm-block it sets the display for sm and all screens greater than sm. How do I invert it?

Answer (score 1):

Can just use the built in Bootstrap classes to hide on smaller screens. 
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/display/#hiding-elements

Would look something like this (untested)

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container d-none d-lg-block">
  <div class="card mb-3">
    <h5 class="card-header">Categories</h5>
    <div class="card-body">
      <h5><a href="http://rtss2.loc/info">All</a></h5>
      Categories here
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

All it does is check media queries on the screen width and apply `display:none` if the screen size is lower than the threshold you put.

Comment: but I want to not hide all card. I want collapse it. Like navigation menu - on small screens it collapsed and need to push button with three lines to show menu elements.

Comment: This answer does not solve the problem but it is the other half of the solution.

Answer (score 0):

You could set it up this way :

```
<div class="card">
   <div class="card-header">
     <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#test-block" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="test-block">
        card header
     </a>
   </div>
   <div id="test-block" class="collapse">
    <div class="card-block">
        card block
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And will do what you're trying to do.

Comment: Grate! But how can I auto collapse it on `sm` screen and not collapse on `lg`?

Comment: This answer does not solve the problem but it is half of the solution.